# Public IP of WCF Service on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8

I created WCF service with local IIS and my project URL is my PC IP like

```
"192.X.X.X"
```

I submit this IP for hosting and got Public IP and it is

```
"224.X.X.X"
```

I browser from internet by writing this Public IP "224.X.X.X" and able to see the WCF Service,
My port is 80 and running,How to call now on Windows Phone 8?

When I change network type,I am getting error like:

```
"System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"
```

Comment: Read the actual exception message, not its type. Using this message you can determine the problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok brother, but do you know how to call? I am adding service reference with "http://192.X.X.X/WcfService1/Service1.svc

Comment: @CodeCaster "Remote Server Not Found", I am getting this exception message.